# php delete mySQL row from <table>

Tags: php

I'm creating a table, each row has a button delete, which is supposed to delete the row. However, now, when I click delete, "nothing happens" and I have to refresh the page to see the results. Please Help.

My code index.php

```
<body>

    <?php include "include/connect.php"; ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Proffesion</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Options</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form action="add.php" method="post">
                <td><input type="text" name="id" disabled size="5"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="prof"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="rank" size="5"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="add" name="watta"></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </form>
        </tr>

        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM staff";
            $vysledek = mysqli_query($link, $query);

            while ($udaj = mysqli_fetch_array($vysledek)):

                if($udaj[4]==0){
                    echo "<tr class='zero'>";
                } else {
                    echo "<tr>";    
                }



                echo "<td>" . $udaj[0] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $udaj[1] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $udaj[2] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $udaj[3] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $udaj[4] . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='btn'><a href=''>";

                ?>
                <form action="delete.php" method="get">
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $udaj[0]; ?>">
                    <input name="what" type="submit" value="DELETE">
                </form>

                <?php
                echo "</a></td>";
                echo "<td class='btn'><a href=''>edit</a></td>";

                echo "</tr>";

            endwhile;


        ?>

    </table>

</body>
```

delete.php

```
<?php

include "include/connect.php";

$toId = ($_GET["id"]);

$queryy = "DELETE FROM staff WHERE id=$toId";
$vysledek = mysqli_query($link, $queryy);

header('Location: http://www.w3dominik.com/x/phptest/');
```

connect.php

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$link = mysqli_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USERNAME, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_DBNAME);
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
```

Live demo at http://www.w3dominik.com/x/phptest/

Comment: are you connected to database in delete.php file?

Comment: If you open the page in two tabs/windows and delete a row in the first tab and refresh that tab, then when you press delete (ON THAT ROW) in the second it works. In other words, we need to see more code... Can you copy all of `index.php` and `delete.php`? (and probably `connect.php` removing your details etc)

Comment: You should be using AJAX for this [see] {http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107}

Comment: Ajax _could_ be used for this, there's no reason that it _should_ be used. Submitting a form and redirecting back to the page is a perfectly acceptable way of doing things...

Answer (score 0):

Look at connect.php and make sure there is NO output.  `header()` won't work if there is any blank spaces or empty lines output before it.  Very easy to have some kind of blank characters put in by mistake.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Ok, now, I've added whole index.php and connect.php. What about now?

Comment: As the documentation says: 'Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called.'  There are a number of empty lines in the file, but it is hard to tell if  they are causing the problem.  I would inline as much as possible (without the `include`) to see if you can get the problem to go away

Comment: This is wrong. The form submits to another page and then is redirected back.. If the `header` redirect wasn't working then it would throw and error saying that `headers have already been sent` and would not redirect back to the form page.